# Using Vertex Buffer Objects with C++ OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, vertex-buffer

I am working on a 3d tile-based strategy game and have read that implementing VBO's will significantly increase the game's frame rate and reduce the cpu usage (sounds great right?).  However, among the tutorials I've looked at I can't quite get a handle on how to implement it.  Has anyone had experience doing this and can either point me to a reliable source or provide sample code that actually works?  Thanks!

Comment: Please post some small, stripped down version of your code that isn't working.  People on SO prefer questions that they can definitively answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are these suitable?

- http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html
- http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object

Comment: +1 for the songho.ca link. Songho's code was by far the most helpful when I started learning about Buffer Objects.